# Issues compiling simple EMA script for PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to compile this simple script that has two EMA's... when one is above the other, it's shaded in between the EMA's. When they are the opposite, then there is a different color shaded inbetween. When I compile, there are a few issues. I don't know how to find out what version of pinescript I even have, or if I can updated it to V5 or not... Please let me know the issues I'm having to get this compiled correctly, Here is my script for it:

```
//@version=5
ta=lib.ema

// Define inputs for the first moving average
length1 = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length 1", group="Settings")
color1 = input("red", title="Color 1", group="Settings")

// Define inputs for the second moving average
length2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="Length 2", group="Settings")
color2 = input("blue", title="Color 2", group="Settings")

// Define input for the shaded area
fill_color_above = input("green", title="Fill Color Above", group="Settings")
fill_color_below = input("orange", title="Fill Color Below", group="Settings")

// Calculate the first moving average
ema1 = ema(close, length1)

// Calculate the second moving average
ema2 = ema(close, length2)

// Plot the first moving average
plot(ema1, color=color1)

// Plot the second moving average
plot(ema2, color=color2)

// Shade the area between the moving averages
fill(ema1, ema2, color=ema1 > ema2 ? fill_color_above : fill_color_below, transp=70)
```

I tried compiling and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues on your code :
In pinescript, you must decide if it is an indicator or a strategy
In your case it is an indicator, you should write :

```
indicator("Ema", overlay=true)
```

You are in the version5 of pinescript. The color are defined by color.thenameofthecolor and and the inputs should hint the type of the waited variable.

```
color2 = input.color(color.blue, title="Color 2", group="Settings")
```

The correct code is :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Ema", overlay=true)
// Define inputs for the first moving average
length1 = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length 1", group="Settings")
color1 = input.color(color.red, title="Color 1", group="Settings")

// Define inputs for the second moving average
length2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="Length 2", group="Settings")
color2 = input.color(color.blue, title="Color 2", group="Settings")

// Define input for the shaded area
fill_color_above = input.color(color.green, title="Fill Color Above", group="Settings")
fill_color_below = input.color(color.orange, title="Fill Color Below", group="Settings")

// Calculate the first moving average
ema1 = ta.ema(close, length1)

// Calculate the second moving average
ema2 = ta.ema(close, length2)

// Plot the first moving average
plot1 = plot(ema1, color=color1)

// Plot the second moving average
plot2 = plot(ema2, color=color2)

// Shade the area between the moving averages
fill(plot1, plot2, color=color.new(ema1 > ema2 ? fill_color_above : fill_color_below, transp=70))
```

You should read this, is it very easy to understand to improve your pinescript coding : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/primer/First_steps.html